# Ext JS - using viewModel for storing permissions or other ‘non-public’ data

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewmodel

I am wondering what's the proper approach for the applications with different role permissions.  I’ve thought that after login, the server sends some predefined role and based on that role individual panels can be restricted or displayed.  So, I stored that value in the viewModel of the main view, like

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main',

    data: {
        user_id : null,
        user_name : '',
        role : '',
    },
    
});
```

And later in the application I check the stored value of role, and based on that restrict some actions. But, I realized that this is ridiculous because viewModel can be easily accessed through console and the value of ‘role’ can be changed. For example:

`Ext.getCmp('main').getViewModel().data.role = 'Admin'`

But what is the right way to store that info? This is very important not only for permission –role based applications, but also for storing other data. So, I suppose that is a trivial problem, but I really don’t’ understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not a trivial question. I don't think there is any proper way to achieve what you would like to do. Regardless the framework you are using it is client side js code what can be altered/hacked from the console. You can try to hide your security logic by obfuscating your code or on some other clever ways but it is just false sense of security and you can not stop an experienced js developer to work it around.

If security is really matters in your application then rather than hiding components on the UI try to restrict data/API access as you can more securely control access at the backend side. I.e. do not spend too much time to make your client side more secure than it is by using your ViewModel approach. But make sure that even is the client side security is breached and someone can grant Admin right then this user will see your hidden panels only but not getting the data from your API.

I.e. your API should not send all data to the client and it shouldn't be the client's responsibility to control data access. Your API should only send that data to the client what the roles of the authenticated user allows.

**Edit to clear the misunderstanding based on the author's comment.**

When your client authenticates the user it sends back the role. But this role should only be used to control the UI (show/hide panels and other controls).
When your client requests data from the server it should not send the role in the request only the authentication data (i.e. user credentials). Then your server should look up the correct role based on the received credentials and only send that data back in the response what is allowed by the given role.
On this way even if your viewModel hacked the user can see the controls allowed for that role but will not see the data as you will not populate that as the server response doesn't contain it.

Comment: thank you very much for your extensive answer. I am beginner and I don’t understand the logic behind it.  Yes, I used hiding components on the UI just as an exemplar of storing data somewhere in the application. But, the problem is general. You said that the server will send data to the client depending on the roles. But, first the server receives a request from the client, and if user changed the value of the role, than checking on the server doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: The server should not rely on the role what the client sends but it should determine the role based on the logged in user. The client should send the logged in user's credentials (username/password hash or a token) then the server should use these credentials and look up the user roles. Then send only the data allowed by the given role.